# WordPress: form redirect after submit

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, redirect

How can I implement a redirect after a custom form submission with PHP in WordPress?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['send'])) {     
  $email = trim($_POST['email']);
  if(empty($email)) {
    echo '<div class="error">Please enter your email.</div>';
  } else {
    if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      echo '<div class="error">Email is not valid.</div>';
    } else {        
      //redirect
      ?><script>window.location = "<?php echo home_url('/thank-you/');?>"</script><?php
    }
  }
}
?>
<form method="post" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" value="<?php  if(!empty($email)) echo $email; ?>" placeholder="Enter your email..." />
  </div>
  <button type="submit" name="send" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>
</form>
```

This is a simple implementation of a custom form which I want to redirect to another site after submit. It works already with javascript, but maybe exists a better way to implement this redirect with PHP?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also consider these 2 solutions as well

first solution to create a function for java script redirect in functions.php and call when ever you want like this

```
function redirect($url){
    $string = '<script type="text/javascript">';
    $string .= 'window.location = "' . $url . '"';
    $string .= '</script>';
    echo $string;
}
```

second solution is to make your wordpress index.php look like this

```
ob_start();
/*content of your index.php here*/
ob_flush();
```

Comment: Thank you I already created a redirect function, but what causes your second solution? :)

Comment: Output buffering should start before anything sent/echoed to the browser.

Answer (score 9):

try this

```
<?php wp_redirect( home_url('/thank-you/') ); exit; ?>
```

Comment: I tried this before, but this form is included in the content section of my frontpage, so the headers are already sent

Comment: You dont have any idea? :(

Comment: it doesn't matter where ever is your form just copy your PHP logic to top of the page. if your condition match than your code will work and redirect accordingly. it's not mandatory to put your PHP logic just above or below of form.

Comment: So I have to modify the wordpress header.php for each redirection, because all forms will included in the content of a site?

Comment: So you have form on each page?

Comment: Then should be the javascript solution the best solution. I thought maybe it exists a hook or something, which allowed to use a PHP or WordPress redirect after get_header(). Nope not on each Page, but if I want redirect from on page to another page I have to copy my PHP logic for each form in the header.php, so if I want a multistep form   should the javascript solution the best.

Comment: in that case you can consider javascript solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wp_redirect(home_url('/thank-you/'));` or `header('Location: '.home_url('/thank-you/')); exit();`. In some cases only the latter worked for me. As of doing it with javascript, it does not make much sense when you have dedicated HTTP header for this.

As of the concern with already loaded form, you should do better code organization or use buffer functions like `ob_start(); ... ; echo ob_get_clean();`.